# /usr/local/bin/mitmproxy: No such script

Tags: mitmproxy

I'm trying to have `mitmproxy` do the `tls_passthrough` but I get the `/usr/local/bin/mitmproxy: No such script`

I'm running the command `sudo mitmproxy --set stream_large_bodies=1 --set block_global=false --showhost -s tls_passthrough.py`

System Information

```
sudo mitmproxy --version
Mitmproxy: 4.0.4
Python: 3.6.8
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.1 11 Sep 2018
Platform: Linux-4.15.0-58-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encounter same problem.

solution: makesure your `xxx.py` in `mitmdump -s xxx.py` path is correct

reason: the **script** in `No such script` means `the script file` = normally is `xxx.py`

you here: makesure the current path of running this your `mitmproxy  -s tls_passthrough.py` can find the file `tls_passthrough.py`

you can check it by:

```sh
pwd
ls -l
```

make sure can find `tls_passthrough.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you typo: N.B. ERROR [missing leading "-" from "--set"]

```
mitmproxy -set upstream_bind_address=docs.mitmproxy.org -s tls_passthrough.py
```

will produce the, (slightly misleading error):

```
/usr/local/bin/mitmdump: No such script
```

when there is nothing wrong with the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your the path with this.

```
which mitmproxy
```

and you can move that to /usr/local/bin/

Comment: When I do `which mitmproxy` I get `/usr/local/bin/mitmproxy` but when I try `sudo mitmproxy --set stream_large_bodies=1 --set block_global=false --showhost -s /usr/local/bin/mitmproxy/examples/complex/tls_passthrough.py` or `sudo mitmproxy --set stream_large_bodies=1 --set block_global=false -s /usr/local/bin/mitmproxy/tls_passthrough.py` I still get the `/usr/local/bin/mitmproxy: No such script`

Comment: `mitmproxy` works when I run it without the `-s tls_passthrough.py`

Comment: @nadermx have you solved this issue? I am asking because I just encountered it and I solved it. The solution is that mitmproxy needs to locate that script. Please confirm if you are using mitmproxy in a docker environment

Answer (score 0):

I guess `mitmdump` doesn't support **relative** paths. I got the full path of the script, e.g. `/workspace/example/scripts/add_cargo_auth_header.py`:

```
mitmdump -s /workspace/example/scripts/add_cargo_auth_header.py
```

That worked for me.